# backbone.js: possible to push <script type="text/template> content to an external file

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone and in my code I have a lot of `text/template` content that I'd like to push to an external file (`templates\name-of-template.js`?) and then load dynamically. Is there an easy way to do this? When I try to link to the file with `<script type="text/template src='whatever'>` it does not work.

Comment: What benefit are you seeking by moving it to a separate file?

Comment: What should the browser do? I think you're making some wrong assumptions about how the script tag works. You'll have to request those templates via ajax calls, not script includes.

Comment: don't provide a src attribute for the template, give it an id - then select the id in your javascript and use innerHTML to get what's inside the script block

Comment: Are you talking about precompiling your templates?

Comment: yeah I'm basically looking to make my index.html more readable and easier to modify by pushing contents to other files, sort of the same way that you would have a separate .css file rather than inline styling; if this is not a best practice, I'm definitely open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest thing to do is load the file w/ Ajax.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.getTemplate();
    },
    getTemplate: function() {
        var self = this;

        $.ajax({ url: "some/html/template.html" }).done(function( content ) {
            self.template = _.template( content );
            self.render();
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template({}) );
    }
});
```

Also, if you were using something like require.js you can use the `text!` plugin...

```
define( [ "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "text!some/html/template.html" ],
    function( _, Backbone, HtmlTemplate ) {

    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.template = _.template( HtmlTemplate );
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html( this.template({}) );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle of this? I can't get this to work. I'm thinking because it is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all templates in a separate js file, something like:

```
App.Templates.Product = [
"<span><%= screen %></span>"
].join("");
```

Or start learning RequireJs. That way you can have a file for each model, collection, view, router and template.

Hope it helps